# Translating bash to python; "dd" command "iflag=skip_bytes" how can be converted?

Tags: python, bash

I'm trying to transform a bash script to python, and I have a piece of code that I want to understands better. The script:

```
dd < "$file" skip=$start count=$((end - start)) iflag=skip_bytes 2> /dev/null |
        (
            if [ -n "$dir" ]; then
                mkdir -p -- "$dir/$subdir"
                cd -- "$dir/$subdir"
            fi
            cpio -i "$@"
        )
```

My understanding is that I read from a file I junk over "$start" bytes and go further `count` bytes.
So I presume I can do this with `seek`.

How do I translate `iflag=skip_bytes` to python ?

Comment: "How do I translate ``iflag=skip_bytes`` to python ?" You already did if you interpret ``skip`` as bytes. It would be blocks otherwise.

Comment: You might want to add the appropriate help/man information for your platform. There is no ``iflag`` parameter for BSD ``dd``, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/dd-invocation.html#dd-invocation

> ‘skip=n’
>
> Skip n ‘ibs’-byte blocks in the input file before copying. If ‘iflag=skip_bytes’ is specified, n is interpreted as a byte count rather than a block count.

So, if you *didn't* have `iflag=skip_bytes` in your bash script, you'd have to multiply `$start` by the block size before seeking. But since the `iflag=skip_bytes` *is* there, no multiplication is necessary and you only need to seek by `$start` bytes.

Comment: Same goes for `count` which normally counts in blocks, but uses bytes if `iflag=skip_bytes` is there.